# Do conditional branches update flags in ARMv8

Tags: assembly, arm, armv8

I am trying to achieve something similar to the following C code:

```
if(x<0)
{
    <code A>
}
else if(x == 0)
{
    <code B>
}
else        //x > 0
{
    <code C>
}
postIf code
```

So i was wondering if I could do this by doing the following in ARMv8, AArch64 instruction set:

```
    cmp x_r, 0     //x_r macro for x19
    b.lt neg
    b.gt pos

    <code B>
    b postIf

neg:
    <code A>
    b postIf
pos:
    <code C>
postIf:
    <postIf Code>
```

Does this work? Do flags stay set (or not set) after checking a conditional branch?

Comment: the arm documentation indicates that a branch does not modify the flags.  they also list the instructions that modify the flags.

Comment: also trying a test program you will see that the compiler assumes/knows that the flags are not affected.

Comment: There are a lot of conditionals in ARMv8 that should help you. https://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/41836-102-1-229511/ARM.Reference_Manual.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should work fine. Branch instructions do not modify the flags.